# Function within if-statement not returning a value, instead getting "Name Error"

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, fuzzywuzzy

I am doing some fuzzy matching on addresses and am filtering on a high score. IF that score exists in my data set then I want to call another function that looks at the data and checks to see if there are sales/calls associated with it.

I want to ultimately return a list of values that fit the criteria in that function. While debugging I can see The "sales_and_calls_test" function works. I see the values getting appended to my lists, however,  when I go to the next iteration I see my lists in my debug watch change from a value to a "Name Error: name "call_list + sales_list" not defined

Can someone please look over my syntax and show me what Im missing? Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
def sales_and_calls_test(v_sales, v_calls):
  calls_list = []
  sales_list = []
  if v_sales > 1:
    print(v_sales, v._1)
    sales_list.append(v_sales)

  if  v_calls > 1:
      print(v_calls, v._1)
      calls_list.append(v_calls)
  
  return calls_list, sales_list


for v in match_table.itertuples():
    #print(v)
    if not string_len_test(l.Address_1, v.Address_2):
       
       lev_score = lev(l.Address_1, v.Address_2)
       fuzz_score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(l.Address_1, v.Address_2)
       if  fuzz_score >= 90:
          sales_and_calls_test(v._6, v._7)
          #print(lev_score, fuzz_score)
        else: 
          if fuzz_score == 87: 
            print('close', v.Address, l.Address_2, v._1, v._6, v._7, v._8)
            print(lev_score, fuzz_score)
    
    else:
      continue

##*** side note does anyone know why after I perform itertuples() 
## that some of my column's change from their names to _number?
```

Comment: Your indentation is all wonky on that last `if/else`, and I don't see any `for` loops so I'm not sure what "next iteration" you're talking about.  Could you include the full exception message including stacktrace?

Comment: Did you accidentally write `call_list` somewhere when you meant `calls_list`?

Comment: And v_6 instead of v._6?

Comment: @Samwise I've got a few for loops, Ill add in the first one, hopefully that will help. Any advice with writing multiple if statements would be greatly appreciated.  And, no I kept the only time I referenced both calls_list/sales_list   was in the function return statement. And the  v references look ok

Comment: Since you haven't included the full exception/stacktrace I don't think there's anything anyone can do to help.  I don't see any code here that could have possibly raised the error you're describing.

Comment: @aero8991 When you say that it showed `Name Error: name "call_list + sales_list is not defined`, did it actually show the exact same thing? If it did, then, it is a typing mistake and please rectify it (it must be `calls_list`). If it didn't, see if it showed `Name Error: name "calls_list + sales_list is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to make my first function return a true/false.

Then I realized that I needed to do a better job comparing the different strings, length was too generic. Instead I opted with using Jaro distance.

I set a condition for the distance and then if that condition as met I returned a value "True"

That reduced my data by a lot! then I called the "sales_and_calls_test" function
and I updated the return values to return the list and if it doesnt fit the criteria then pass (which reduced my data even more!)

Here's my updates:

```
def sales_and_calls_test(v_sales, v_calls):

  if v_sales > 1:    
    sales_list.append(v_sales)
    return sales_list
  elif  v_calls > 1:     
      calls_list.append(v_calls)
      return calls_list
  else:
    pass

  

for v in match_table.itertuples():
    #print(v)
    if string_len_test(l.Address_1, v.Address_2) == True:
       
       lev_score = lev(l.Address_1, v.Address_2)
       fuzz_score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(l.Address_1, v.Address_2)
       if  fuzz_score >= 90:
          sales_and_calls_test(v._6, v._7)
          #print(lev_score, fuzz_score)
        else: 
          if fuzz_score == 87: 
            print('close', v.Address, l.Address_2, v._1, v._6, v._7, v._8)
            print(lev_score, fuzz_score)
    
    else:
      continue
```